# Identify element in UI Automation in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ui-automation

I am trying to learn something new in VBA and now I am working on UI Automation.
There is a browser that I am trying to interact with in specific way and everything is OK till I encountered an element with no AutomationID nor ClassName nor Name 
How can identify that element?

[image]

The snapshot is taken from "Accessibility Insights For Windows" tool

Here's the code I used till now

```
Rem References: UIAutomationClient
Rem ------------------------------
Dim MyElement As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
Dim MyElement1 As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement

'Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Public Enum oConditions
eUIA_NamePropertyId
eUIA_AutomationIdPropertyId
eUIA_ClassNamePropertyId
eUIA_LocalizedControlTypePropertyId
End Enum

Sub myDemo()
Dim AppObj As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
Dim oInvokePattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Dim oAutomation As New CUIAutomation ' the UI Automation API\
Dim oPattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern

Set AppObj = WalkEnabledElements("Y_browser")

Set MyElement = AppObj.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_AutomationIdPropertyId, "1"))
Set MyElement1 = MyElement.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_ClassNamePropertyId, "Edit"))
Set oPattern = MyElement1.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_LegacyIAccessiblePatternId)
oPattern.SetValue ("http://student.moe.gov.eg/new/serch_students.aspx")
Set MyElement = AppObj.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_NamePropertyId, "GO"))
Set oInvokePattern = MyElement.GetCurrentPattern(UIAutomationClient.UIA_InvokePatternId)
oInvokePattern.Invoke

Set MyElement1 = AppObj.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_ClassNamePropertyId, "Shell Embedding"))
Set MyElement = MyElement1.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_ClassNamePropertyId, "Shell DocObject View"))
Set MyElement1 = MyElement.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_ClassNamePropertyId, "Internet Explorer_Server"))
Set MyElement = MyElement1.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_NamePropertyId, "الادارة الالكترونية للتعليم ...بيانات التلميذ"))
Set MyElement1 = MyElement.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_AutomationIdPropertyId, "100"))

Rem Here's where I am stuck at ....
Set MyElement = MyElement1.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_LocalizedControlTypePropertyId, "item"))

Stop

End Sub


Function PropCondition(UiAutomation As CUIAutomation, Prop As oConditions, Requirement As String) As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
Select Case Prop
    Case 0
        Set PropCondition = UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_NamePropertyId, Requirement)
    Case 1
        Set PropCondition = UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId, Requirement)
    Case 2
        Set PropCondition = UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_ClassNamePropertyId, Requirement)
    Case 3
        Set PropCondition = UiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIAutomationClient.UIA_LocalizedControlTypePropertyId, Requirement)
End Select
End Function

Function WalkEnabledElements(strWindowName As String) As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
Dim oAutomation As New CUIAutomation
Dim condition1 As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
Dim condition2 As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
Dim walker As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationTreeWalker
Dim element As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement

Set walker = oAutomation.ControlViewWalker
Set element = walker.GetFirstChildElement(oAutomation.GetRootElement)

Do While Not element Is Nothing
    Rem Debug.Print element.CurrentName
    If InStr(1, element.CurrentName, strWindowName) > 0 Then
        Set WalkEnabledElements = element
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set element = walker.GetNextSiblingElement(element)
Loop
End Function

Function GetElement(elementalist As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement)
On Error Resume Next
Dim oAutomation As New CUIAutomation
Dim walker As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationTreeWalker

Set walker = oAutomation.ControlViewWalker
Dim element1 As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElementArray
Dim element2 As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement

Dim childtree As UIAutomationClient.TreeScope
Debug.Print elementalist.CurrentName
Dim condition1 As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
Set condition1 = oAutomation.CreateTrueCondition
Set element1 = elementalist.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, condition1)
DoEvents
If element1.Length <> 0 Then
    Set element2 = elementalist.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, condition1)
End If

Do While Not element2 Is Nothing
    Dim oPattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern
    Set oPattern = element2.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_LegacyIAccessiblePatternId)

    Debug.Print element2.CurrentName & "|" & oPattern.CurrentValue

    If oPattern.CurrentName = "Notification" Then
        Set MyElement = element2
        Exit Function
    End If

    Debug.Print element2.CurrentClassName

    Debug.Print element2.CurrentAutomationId

    GetElement element2
    Debug.Print element2.CurrentName
    If Not MyElement Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Set element2 = walker.GetNextSiblingElement(element2)
Loop

End Function

Function GetElement1(elementalist As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement)
On Error Resume Next
Dim oAutomation As New CUIAutomation
Dim walker As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationTreeWalker

Set walker = oAutomation.ControlViewWalker
Dim element1 As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElementArray
Dim element2 As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement

Dim childtree As UIAutomationClient.TreeScope
Debug.Print elementalist.CurrentName
Dim condition1 As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
Set condition1 = oAutomation.CreateTrueCondition
Set element1 = elementalist.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, condition1)
DoEvents
If element1.Length <> 0 Then
    Set element2 = elementalist.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, condition1)
End If

Do While Not element2 Is Nothing
    Dim oPattern As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern
    Set oPattern = element2.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_LegacyIAccessiblePatternId)

    Debug.Print element2.CurrentName & "|" & oPattern.CurrentValue

    If element2.CurrentName = "Save" Then
        Set MyElement = element2
        Exit Function
    End If

    Debug.Print element2.CurrentClassName

    Debug.Print element2.CurrentAutomationId

    GetElement element2
    Debug.Print element2.CurrentName
    If Not MyElement Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Set element2 = walker.GetNextSiblingElement(element2)
Loop
End Function

Function AddReference() As Boolean
Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim chkRef As VBIDE.Reference
Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
Set vbProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

For Each chkRef In vbProj.References
    If chkRef.Name Like "*IBM PCOMM 4.01*" Then
        GoTo Flush
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo Hell:
vbProj.References.AddFromFile Environ("systemroot") & "\system32\uiautomationcore.dll"

Hell:
If Err.Number = 48 Then
    AddReference = False
ElseIf Err.Number = 0 Then
    AddReference = True
End If
Flush:
Set vbProj = Nothing
Set VBAEditor = Nothing
End Function
```

And this is a link to the browser I am working on
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tDGa2iiMpEBbFVc-jMHdMB2nA1lgVFac

Comment: Can you use the relationship between table and then child item in some way?

Comment: No in fact. I have no great experience ..I am just trying to learn in this aspect

Comment: I have only used UiAutomationCore.dll, which I assume is what you are using, years ago and don't know it well :-(

Comment: Are there any articles or tutorials related to using UiAutomationCore.dll in VBA (for beginners)?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=UiAutomationCore+vba  Might have a look myself!

Comment: The first three videos in the results are where I got the code ..

Comment: what are the steps in words that you are performing up to the attempt to get that target element?

Comment: In the code `http://student.moe.gov.eg/new/serch_students.aspx` I navigate to this url then I would like to input some text in the first textbox on the page (that's all for now)

Comment: How can I access element within table as appeared in the snapshot?

Comment: Hi, I am going to try and use the tool you indicated as Explore.exe is not showing a tree structure for me. The icon is missing from the toolbar. That or I may resort to  Spy++ but I won't get to look at it again until later in week.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks a lot for your interest. I am not in hurry so take your time and come back with treasures :)

Comment: @YasserKhalil - For useful links about UI Automation, here is [a list](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-uiautomationclient-to-automate-the-save-as-file-download-in-ie11.1086615/post-5355319) that you could have a look into.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Did you find a way on how to identify it ? I am also stuck on same problem !

Answer (score 1):

If the element has no Name, AutomationID nor ClassName property, you can have a look at other properties. Here is a [list of the UIA properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-automation-element-propids?redirectedfrom=MSDN#UIA_NamePropertyId) that you have access to.

Seems like you could use the `UIA_ControlTypePropertyId` in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already tried such line `Set MyElement = MyElement1.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, PropCondition(oAutomation, eUIA_LocalizedControlTypePropertyId, "50029"))` but doesn't work .. I am not sure of the ControlType `ControlType DataItem(50029)` ..I noticed ProcessId but I can't implement any other property in the code as the code is restricted to the four main properties you have referred to.